# Pipe Closed Error when adding remote interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, openedx

I follow the step of [official docs](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Setting-up-PyCharm-for-edX-development) to run open edx on pycharm. But I have difficulty in installing the remote pycharm interpreter. It gives me a error -- "Pipe closed". See image below.
[image]
After clicking python interpreter, I get "Pipe closed": 
[image]

This error make the remote interpreter unable to work well. When running the application, it will give me error -- `Error running LMS: Can't run remote python interpreter: Error connecting to remote host:127.0.0.1`

What is the problem with `Pipe closed`? How can I resolve it? Thank you very much!!

Comment: can you ssh into that box and type python and it pulls up a python interpretter? it sounds like you dont have a remote host there

Comment: @JoranBeasley You are correct!! I found the installation for the remote host didn't successfully (edxapp was set up as expected). Now after reinstallation,  the error is resolved. Thank you!